# Real Analysis Closed and Bounded Set Question

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose K is a nonempty closed and bounded subset of a metric space X and x $\in$ X. Show the following hypothesis fails: There is a p $\in$ K such that, for all other q $\in$ K,
*d(p,x)* $\leq$ *d(q,x)*. I know this hypothesis holds  if K is compact, so clearly the counterexample must not come from $\mathbb{R}$ because of the Heine-Borel theorem. Much appreciated!

Comment: You could try $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ \ {0} isn't closed though since singletons are closed, so the complement is open. :/

Comment: I meant just what user103254 wrote ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think DF suggested $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ as a candidate for $X$. It is a metric space with the metric induced from $\mathbb R$.

With this $X$, try $x=-1$ and $K=\{x\in X: 0\le x\le 1\}$ (which is a *closed* subset of $X$).